# dynamically call a typed function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm using the the library https://github.com/ivanhofer/typesafe-i18n

This library generates strongly typed translation information and functions, like below. (the following examples are simplified)

```
export type MyTranslations = {
  Hello: (arg: { field: unknown}) => string
  Bye: (arg: { field: unknown, date: unknown}) => string
  Foo: (arg: { field: unknown}) => unknown
  Bar: (arg: { max: unknown}) => unknown,
  test: string // this is just here to show that not every property of MyTranslations needs to be a function
}

const translations: MyTranslations = {
  Hello: (arg: { field: unknown}) => 'hello',
  Bye: (arg: { field: unknown, date: unknown}) => 'bye',
  Foo: (arg: { field: unknown}) => 'foo',
  Bar: (arg: { max: unknown}) => 'bar',
  test: '' // this is just here to show that not every property of MyTranslations needs to be a function
}
```

Now in my code I have a function which should translate messages dynamically, it does not know exactly what I has to translate.
Through TS typing information it knows what I might translate (with `keyof`).
Here is the code so far.
I spend already quite some time and I'm not sure if it is even possible or sensible, but I just want to know :)

```
// preparation
interface MyParams {
  [index: string]: boolean | number | string | undefined
  field?: keyof MyTranslations
}

interface Result {
  transKey: keyof MyTranslations,
  params?: MyParams
}

const results: Result[] = [
  {
    transKey: 'Hello',
    params: {
      field: 'Bye'
    }
  },
  {
    transKey: 'Bar',
    params: {
      max: 'test'
    }
  }
] 

type PickByType<T, V> = {
  [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V | undefined ? P : never]: T[P]
}
```

the translation function

```
function translate(results: Result[]) {
  results.forEach((result: Result) => {
      type A = PickByType<MyTranslations, Function>
      type C = keyof A
     
      if(result.params) {
        type T = typeof result.params
        type Req = Required<T>

        const req = result.params as Req
        
        const func = translations[result.transKey]
        type F = typeof func
        

        const f = translations as A
        f[result.transKey as C](req)

      }
  })
}

translate(results)
```

The problem is here `f[result.transKey as C](req)`

**Error**

```
Argument of type 'Required<MyParams>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ field: unknown; } & { field: unknown; date: unknown; } & { field: unknown; } & { max: unknown; }'.
  Property 'date' is missing in type 'Required<MyParams>' but required in type '{ field: unknown; date: unknown; }'
```

Which makes sense. Typescript expects an intersection type.
So I thought maybe I can create this type somehow (holding all the required parameters `field, max and date` and then, according to this type information create a new object of this new type holding this information, like so in pseudo code

```
type D = getAllParametersFromTypeAsIntersectionType() // <- this is easy
const newParams = createNewParamsAsTypeD(result.params)
```

Any ideas?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=48&ssc=1&pln=74&pc=19#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyiAqUCGA7AZwBscYBLCQuAXjgG8BYAKDjgAlgiiIAuOAChxQA5nzpwAZmU4ATPgFc8AazwQA7ngC%20AShoA%20OARhQyeYc1YAhRMD6CRYydKJy4ilerwAaODNK23ZVUNHX1DY1NzFjgAMQheASFReidZBSDPUOoDd2C8CzhLITskxwBbHBB0jxDdbMCa7wLWGGAjPiMTM2ZNZmYAY0ojBFxCEnIhvgxsfGJSCipaRmiOLgT7ZPEpNIa8rIMAcgALTm4DrwLrAI3HbZdqvJ8-VofMusOAIxtzgrj10pSd1cuTeYQOEniP2iRSgJQcKQqVV2oPqBw%20QihLTaMD4BwOPT6TAA9ES4MAAG7AKCIGBHSJwHAfCCUuD9fCqeAfVD9I74YTAGSE0ytKASHD9VAYAAKQhwZQI9AKAG1TDJQB0ImYALp8JkQIjAfBwAA%20cDw8jKXKgJvCXWENsUaqkeAFBSBAH4%20EpgIgIBJ0FhRnMJoQCUxmMKqWKJXAAEpteREeDLFpBgDSPq9Pr9AZmY3mQwu0TAsvlnoDMtw8rDAyG8CgCaTBD48YIiZgSq1NDgSoKKdYI1mGcQuNWZyLA7gJarzcV0UnQNxV3x87gvWimgnc8nxiHmbgBxhmIH07ls-7k8RuNaRhXk-XrHXXcJSBQcClZH6SmsmGQwAAPJgPgAGoGEsypSnAphwN6vr%20pgDIKpgSpSl2oCtHgMgKsBDqYcAzoCnA7rvnAfAupSUA6nAyGoTWTASIo-QhoO%20atPwDZtk2LaNh2Wq6P2HHtgQAB0EJQAAouKRz8OxPHcZxMDvNuk5QRIskKcJp5lqJzgyPxhIqWuBkqa%20qAAILdh%20X4-n%20-7TEG4wLAQPgxIxIZ6M0A6mXAADC3awTmZmeXAwWqep7aaaWBD6auO5-tR3amTmglJpFM6hS08XxgAjt2OXyGQDYyIBHnhrFA6DIQ8D9N2KUwGlZ6IXGwDZRlIXlawlXDAxeA1bQu6sU5Sp1cJA0EMOWptd5MSJX%20OY9f0bXGYZXXwP6-UOQWVA4AqQUdZIw08aN6Y%20k1PlauFqVadFy0Dg%20a7aHRY3jMAl0wDdZWEkAA)

Comment: There's quite a bit of type juggling you're doing whose purpose isn't obvious to me. Your basic issue is that you can't do this with unions but need to use generics in a particular way, as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). If I refactor your types for that it looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPJAZN). Does that mostly address the question (with the exception of ... whatever else was going on in there that you didn't actually describe in words)? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Comment: this looks exactly what I was looking for.
Sorry, if my question was a bit messy, I spent a lot of time on the issue before I asked here, maybe my brain was already done ;) 
If you can tell me which parts were unclear I will edit the question so future reader have a better understanding.

Add your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I'd say the stuff with `if(result.params?.field) { }` is unmotivated here; you might have some use for it, but it just seems extraneous.  Same thing with `test`; it looks like you spend effort in the question carving up `MyTranslations` to avoid non-function properties, but it's not really the core of what you're asking about.

Comment: code has been updated to reflect jcalz's suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to treat `result.params` as an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types). First of all, it's not one: it would need to have every single property (e.g., `{field: ⋯, date: ⋯, max: ⋯}`) but in practice you're only passing the properties needed by `translations[result.transKey]` for the particular `result.transKey`.  The reason TypeScript expects and intersection is because it has no idea about the intended higher order relationship between `result.transKey` and `result.params`.  Your `Result` type doesn't actually encode any such relationship (you could write `{ transKey: 'Hello', params: { max: 'Bye' } }` and it would be accepted, even though that's not the right `params` type for `Hello`). And even if you did encode it as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of acceptable types for each `transKey`, it wouldn't automatically work inside the `forEach()` callback because TypeScript can't deal well with "correlated unions".

This lack of direct support for correlated unions  is covered in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). The recommended approach is to refactor to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in a particular way, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

The idea is to write a "base" object type that represents the underlying key-value relationship you care about, and then all your operations should use that type, generic [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that type, and generic indexes into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.

Your base object type would be

```
interface TransArg {
    Hello: { field: unknown; };
    Bye: { field: unknown; date: unknown; };
    Foo: { field: unknown; };
    Bar: { max: unknown; };
}
```

You can actually compute this from `MyTranslations` as follows:

```
type TransKey = {
  [K in keyof MyTranslations]: MyTranslations[K] extends (arg: any) => any ? K : never
}[keyof MyTranslations]
// type TransKey = "Hello" | "Bye" | "Foo" | "Bar"

type TransArg = { [K in TransKey]: Parameters<MyTranslations[K]>[0] }
```

The `TransKey` thing is essentially `keyof PickByType<MyTranslations, Function>` in your version. Note that this is all just to avoid the `test` key, which is sort of a distraction here from your main issue, but it's easily overcome so that's fine.

And then `TransArg` maps over `TransKey` to grab just the parameter type for the method.  Now we need to rewrite the type of `translations` in terms of `TransArg`, as follows:

```
const _translations: { [K in TransKey]: (arg: TransArg[K]) => void } =
  translations;
```

This isn't really doing anything other than verifying that `translations` is of that mapped type, but now we can use `_translations` in place of `translations` and the compiler will be better able to follow what it does for arbitrary key `K`, since it's explicitly encoded in the type (as opposed to `MyTranslations` which only has such information implicitly).

We can now write `Result` more accurately as a *distributive object type* (as coined in ms/TS#47109):

```
type Result<K extends TransKey = TransKey> =
  { [P in K]: { transKey: P, params?: TransArg[P] } }[K]
```

So `Result<K>` for a particular `K` is just the type of `Result` suitable for that `transKey`.  And `Result<TransKey>` is the full union of `Result<K>` for each `K` in `TransKey`.  And the [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) `TransKey` means that writing just `Result` gives us that full union.  Now you can write

```
const results: Result[] = [
  {
    transKey: 'Hello',
    params: {
      field: 'Bye'
    }
  },
  {
    transKey: 'Bar',
    params: {
      max: 'test'
    }
  }
]
```

And if you tried to mix up the `params` there (e.g., use `{max: 'test'}` for `'Hello'`) you'd get an error.

We're almost done. Now we can call `results.forEach()` with a *generic* callback function:

```
function translate(results: Result[]) {
  results.forEach(<K extends TransKey>(result: Result<K>) => {
    if (result.params) _translations[result.transKey](result.params);
  })
}
```

Inside the callback, `_translations[result.transKey]` is of the single generic type `(arg: TransArg[K]) => void`, while the type of `result.params` is `TransArg[K]` (well, it was `TransArg[K] | undefined` but we've eliminated `undefined` by the check `if (result.params)`).  And so you have a single function type that accepts an argument corresponding exactly to the argument we're passing it.  So that compiles with no problem.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyiAqUCGA7AZwBscYBLCQuAXjgG8BYAKDjgAlgiiIAuOAChxQA5nzpwAZmU4ATPgFc8AazwQA7njgBfAJQ0AfHAIwoZPMOasAQomB9BIsZOlE5cRSvV4ANHBmk7d2VVDW09akNjU3NLOAAxCF4BIVF6Z1kFYK8wgyDPDVirIXsUpwBbHBBM-M1dXI8Qn1iYYGM+KLMLJi1mZgBjSmMEXEISckG+DGx8YlIKKlpGFnZObhLHNKkMvMaciLgAcgALVYgD70LbddTxLddqxt9-Fofsuv2DgCNbc9iEpIcN3S9x2b3ChgOEkSv2WRSg13KlVeoXeEM+QhhrBabUOB2YPSYzAA9ES4MAAG7AKCIGBHTpwHCfCCUuB9fCqeCfVB9I74YTAGS9JhIFBwaaEADSwEQNHosQA2hK4GY4EppRAJOgsCNZuNCABdSbamZjeYERX6skgFp4GQEZIbfCIcEMvAygD8cCVfDwFKp+PlasQGq14t1Zv1xNJItQYalMtoACIOFwIIm4AAfOCJmzAdNZxP-fPZuGJoUxsU6gCCIll4kVys0celhrgAAUhDgysAWlACAAeKY602DC36eUABktBKJACoEMhY9Xa4tYqwU2tNi43A0vABubR7tdwXNOO47rIaA-PQK7q+H4--M-b5F4A9aI-LazFNIVKqg+8P3xOBZyJIUBkIeAAH0TBNOYJjSBsVWbRBW0BPgwxrYQLRdckIDIGRtBoZph3gwhP2YCsACVWnkIgYH7JVQBtO1KxmeNZRQwxqFies20bL1W3EWDJWlPg218MBOzKAh3Qw5dsLbadtAtcDBngKBaPogg+Bogg6JgeVLVoeVeOPESCHjPgDg3M4Li-OApNwGSxGPVhz2s3M8QcglWC0ezWCWVgsR1KzDjhTFgqcrsdLlBzWD-azsRgbzgu0WICUjQlsokRQ+j1YY4JafhNP07TdK0wz9T0IK4FKgyCAAOihKAAFEcB5fhGKtFj7S4krKoqsqGIlfQXVq1gyE1Abhsa6KZL0GDSL1c16voxqLPjfUZoMubpIIHRPz8nR8XLZbgB27STuyoUgA)

Comment: much appreciate the very detailed answer!